# disableSelection on div class="panel-body"

Tags: javascript, html, draggable

Hi I'm looking for some help.

I'm using FlatLab to build a "draggable and sortable" dashboard.  In the panels I'm adding in charts using Highcharts.  I have this working well with the option to drag the portlets around the screen into the order I wish.

The Issue:

The charts uses a zoom function, so when the mouse is dragged across the chart it moves the panel instead of allowing the zoom function!

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="row-fluid" id="draggable_portlets">
     <div class="sortable">
         <div class="panel inline-block span-4">
    <header class="panel-heading">Utilisation from October 1st
        <span class="tools pull-right">
           <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></a>
           <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-remove"></a>
        </span>
    </header>    
            <div class="panel-body">
               <div id="chart1" style="min-width: 180px; height: '100%'; margin: 0 auto"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

In the javascript I've added in the following along side another similar line of code:

```
$(".panel-body").disableSelection();
```

similar code in the same js file - $(".column").disableSelection();

It feels like I've don the right thing but its not disabling selection on panel-body

Any help is as always appreciated.

Thanks
Rob

[image]

Comment: any errors in your console? are you calling the `disableSelection` in the correct place?

Comment: .disableSelection() disables text selection.  If I understand your question correctly, you're looking to disable the zoom functionality built into the charts you are using, and .disableSelection() doesn't seem to be the correct way to do that.  Furthermore, .disableSelection() is deprecated as of jQuery UI 1.9

Comment: Hi Pete, I'm calling the disable function in the "draggable_portlets" java script code. And there is already the same line of code there for "column" id.

Comment: Hi z416175, you may be onto something here.  In the original demo portlets there were standard blocks of text - thats why the original line of code may have been there.   But to your note - what I'm trying to do is disable the ability to drag the portlet "panel" which contains the chart.  This way I will be able to use the zoon functions of the chart. Hope that helps - I'll add an image to help explain.

Comment: So you want to allow the zoom function in the charts, instead of moving the panel, right? do you still want to be able to move the chart panel? possibly by clicking and dragging on the heading area containing 'utlisation from October 1st'?  or do you not want the chart panel to be draggable at all?

Comment: Yes on the zoom function in the chart and yes on the "be able to move the chart panel by clicking and draging on the heading area" Thanks

Comment: Ok, got to think about this for a few minutes, don't have access to FlatLab code, let you know what I come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it will reactivate the zoom functionality, but I suspect it will.  You should be able to copy and paste this into console to see if it works.  It sets the cancel option of sortable on the chart.

```
$("#draggable_portlets").sortable("option", "cancel", "#chart1");
```

Comment: Hi, you absolutely nailed that one.  Works perfectly.  I added it to the script just after the DraggablePortlet.init();   Thank you very much